# Why should i join the dark brotherhood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to know why i should join the dark brotherhood in skyrim im at the part where i talk with astrid but why should i any answers might help me decide? Nothing has been done sense the first part so i need help deciding?

Answer (score 3):

Well the joining the dark brotherhood gives you unique armor first off, and you can get two more sets of unique armor later on in the story, if you play your cards right. Their are also at least two unique weapons. The dark brotherhood also gives a great story that I recommend completing. It is also a infinite source of gold with the assassination missions after the story is completed. I hope this helped.

Comment: Also Shadowmere